# Jenkins and Phabricator integration

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, phabricator

I am new to jenkins and need to integrate it with phabricator.
I installed jenkins but when I tried to configure it, I can't find Phabricator Section.

It is mentioned that arcanist needs to be installed on jenkins nodes, but I don't know how to do that.

Can anybody help me out?

Here's the repo: https://github.com/uber/phabricator-jenkins-plugin

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First go to manage jenkins --> plugins and install the phabricator plugin. After that you can follow the documentation on the github page. I don't think it's possible to explain that part better.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also to install Arcanist you can follow the [Quick Start](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/arcanist_quick_start/) here.

If you are running Jenkins on a linux server you can quickly install with the command:

```
sudo apt install arcanist
```

Afterwards you can use the `Manage Jenkins` button on the sidebar to navigate to the Plugins Manager page to install the `Phabricator Differential` plugin seen here
[image: Phabricator Differential on Plugin Manager page]